# Error when running msfconsole in arch linux

Tags: archlinux, metasploit

I get this error when running msfconsole in arch linux

```
$ msfconsole         
Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I was searching google for the solution and I found out that installing gem files on msfconsole directory fixes the issue.

So I `cd` to `/opt/metasploit`

then `bundle install`

finally running `msfconsole` inside this directory works.

The problem is if I am outside this directory it's giving me the error again. 
What are the possible causes of this error? 
What are the possible fixes on this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Metasploit needs to run in the context of its own installation directory.

If you install the official metasploit community package from https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/metasploit/ then it will work fine and be set up to run from `$PATH`.

(If you have installed it in some other manner, then obviously you'll need to explain how it was installed in order to let people know how to debug/fix it.)

Comment: Hello I installed it using the community package and the black arch package. They are having the same error. My guess is that because of user permission? I added my current user to the group "wheel" during the installation of arch linux. I am just following the YouTube video. What else should I do so that my current user can access files efficiently